# Android Tab Layout setIcon method only works inside OnTabSelectedListener

Tags: android, material-design, android-tablayout, androidx

I'm trying to set icons to my tab layout's tabs using this code inside the `onCreate` method of the activity

```
tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(R.drawable.icon0);
tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(R.drawable.icon1);
tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(R.drawable.icon2);
```

as it should work perfectly fine because similar `TabLayout.Tab` methods such as

```
tabLayout.getTabAt(0).getOrCreateBadge().setNumber(number);
```

do in the exact same scope, it doesn't.

Weirdly, the same code works if I put it inside tab layout's `OnTabSelectedListener`

```
tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(R.drawable.icon0);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(R.drawable.icon1);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(R.drawable.icon2);

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

    }
});
```

There is no logic behind this as far as I got. Is this a bug or am I missing something? How can I use these methods without using a listener?

I use these versions of the libraries:

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha01'
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue. We have no idea where those `Tab`s are created, what they're linked to, how they're otherwise modified, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set icon to tab after call `setupWithViewPager` method.

```
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
for (int i = 0; i < tabLayout.getTabCount(); i++) {
  tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setIcon(R.drawable.your_icon);
}
```

Comment: Same result happens